# SSRS Report export to PDF is printing previous sub report data in PDF but showing correct in PPT or Doc or TIFF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have one main report in SSRS for example Main_Report.rdl and under Main_Report I have more than 15 sub reports, now there are 3 sub reports which are having same structure but the column and the dataset are different/unique, for example these 3 reports are Report11, Report12 and Report13, now when I am running the report from designer, Report11 is showing correct data, Report12 also showing correct/expected data and Report13 also showing correct/expected data, but when I am exporting to PDF, Report11 is showing correct, but Report12 tablix and Report13 tablix also showing the same data from Report11 tablix which is wrong, but when I am exporting to PPT or Doc or TIFF it is showing correct data in Report11, Report12 and Report13.
Pls suggest what I can do to fix this PDF export issue??

I tried by keeping 3 different stored procedure, keeping 3 different dataset names and also kept databar name unique in all 3 sub reports.

I am expecting the same result set shown in preview to be printed in PDF after exporting to PDF.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. 

A row in the outermost group is being used for a table header. Works fine in VS and report viewer, but when exports to PDF, excel, TIFF, etc the header row never gets updated.

Exporting as XML reveals the XML structure doesn't match the report structure.

Export as XML and take a look.